# Subtracting Two Column With Null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I use the following

```
 select TotalCredits - TotalDebits as Difference
 from 
 (
 select
 (select sum(TOTALAMOUNT) from journal where memberid=48 and CREDIT =1) as TotalCredits,
 (select SUM(totalamount) from Journal where MEMBERID=48 and DEBIT =1) As TotalDebits
 ) temp
```

this returns one field with my difference, the problem i am occuring is that if the table has no credit, but has debits, the temp table contains a NULL value in the TotalCredits Field which prohibts math being done. (Vica Versa on has Credits but no Debits)  I have tried coalese but cant seem how to make it work.

rationally i need to check if:

```
sum(TOTALAMOUNT) from journal where memberid=48 and CREDIT =1 as TotalCredits is 
null then totalcredits = 0 and visa versa
```

sql server 2008

Comment: Can't you replace `NULL` values with 0? `SELECT ISNULL(SUM(TotalAmount), 0) FROM journal WHERE memberid = 48 AND Credit = 1`?

Comment: the criteria of credit = 1 may not yeild any rows so i cannot set data to zero if no rows meet the criteria

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 select ISNULL(TotalCredits,0) - ISNULL(TotalDebits,0) as Difference
 from 
 (
 select
 (select sum(TOTALAMOUNT) from journal where memberid=48 and CREDIT =1) as TotalCredits,
 (select SUM(totalamount) from Journal where MEMBERID=48 and DEBIT =1) As TotalDebits
 ) temp
```

Comment: this also appears to work, thanks guy!  other one is just alittle more condensed without setting null to 0

Answer (score 3):

Change your query to conditional aggregation and it fixes the problem:

```
select sum(case when credit = 1 then TotalAmount else -TotalAmount end) as Difference
from Journal
where memberid = 48 and (credit = 1 or debit = 1);
```

EDIT:

If you have the case where credit and debit could both be 1, then use:

```
select (sum(case when credit = 1 then TotalAmount else 0 end) -
        sum(case when debit = 1 then TotalAmount else 0 end)
       ) as Difference
from Journal
where memberid = 48 and (credit = 1 or debit = 1);
```

Comment: this is exactly what i need, seems to be working both ways too  thanks Gordon!

Comment: Some fringe cases to be wary of: What if both Credit=1 and Debit = 1? What if there are no rows where memberid=48?

Comment: philip you just read my mind, i tested if no rows existed at all, @guy approach is better it still returns a 0 amount if no records exist,  as for debit and credit both selected, that would be a programming error only, because its either one or the other.

Comment: Put an isnull around the sum, and that handles no rows. Credit vs. Debit, if it can only ever be one or the other (never both, never neither), it should just be a not-null bit column (say, "IsCredit").

Answer (score 2):

Hello may be this can also can give the expected result

```
select COALESCE(TotalCredits,0) - COALESCE(TotalDebits,0) as Difference
 from 
 (
 select
 (select sum(TOTALAMOUNT) from journal where memberid=48 and CREDIT =1) as TotalCredits,
 (select SUM(totalamount) from Journal where MEMBERID=48 and DEBIT =1) As TotalDebits
 ) temp
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a sub query using isnull to replace the null with 0 and then make the sum  querys and then the total substraction

Answer (score 0):

Ouch. That query makes my head hurt. [*Discriminant functions*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/discriminant%20function) are your friend and `case` lets you create them easily in SQL. Just state the problem simply.

```
select total_credits = sum( case j.credit when 1 then 1 else 0 end ) ,
       total_debits  = sum( case j.debit  when 1 then 1 else 0 end ) ,
       total_delta   = sum( case j.credit when 1 then 1 else 0 end )
                     - sum( case j.debit  when 1 then 1 else 0 end )
from journal j
where j.memberid = 48
```